# Rallydev API pyral: Is there way to get all defects by Formatted ID in one query?

Tags: python, rest, rally, pyral

I have a list of defects with different IDs. I need to go thru the list and gather fixed / verified defects to separate list.

Could you please advise if there is a way to make in one query (e.g. send a tuple in query) instead of each time send a new get request?

currently it looks like:

```
items = ("DE111", "DE123", "DE345")
defects = []
for item in items:
  criteria = 'FormattedID = "%s"' % item
  response = rally.get('Defect', fetch="Name,State", query=criteria)
  for defect in response:
    defects.append(defect)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a little Python 3 you can string together an 'or' conditional on the Formatted ID... If you don't have Python 3 I'm sure the same thing can be accomplished in 2.  The important part is the ultimate query string which is : (((FormattedID = DE111) OR (FormattedID = DE112)) OR (FormattedID = DE123))

see [an example](http://repl.it/bME/5) on repl.it

```
from functools import reduce
items = ("DE111", "DE112")

def byFormattedId(value): 
   return "(FormattedID = \"%s\")" % value

def ors(statement, value): 
   return "(%s OR %s)" % (statement, value)


x = list(map(byFormattedId, items))
y = reduce(ors, x)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I get error in response each time after trying to submit query with OR statement.

Comment: Sorry, i missed the quotes on the formatted ID criteria values. I have updated the post and tested this through the Rally WSAPI documentation.